# how to customize spacing and colors the bar plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have the following data where A and B belong to two different categories; additionally within A and B, A1 (or B1) belong to subcategories of A and B.  In other words, A1 is in one subcategory and A2 and A3 in another.  Similarly for B.

```
labels= ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']
values= [2, 4, 3, 2.5, 3.5, 4]
```

I would like to do a bar plot where A and B categories as well as sub categories are separated (preferably by different colors).  My attempt is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

index = np.arange(len(labels))

plt.bar(index, values)
plt.ylabel('Values', fontsize=14)
plt.xticks(index, labels, fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I customize the spacing/coloring between the bars?

Comment: Are you groups always in size of 3? A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3 and so on?

Comment: *bar plot where A and B categories as well as sub categories are separated (preferably by different colors).*... Do you want to have 6 colors? each category and each subcategory in different color? Then what is the purpose of coloring?

Comment: *How can I customize the spacing/coloring between the bars?*.... What kind of spacing do you want? Please include these things in your question to make it more clear to the readers.

Comment: They are not always in size of 3 but in this case they are. In the graph above I want to have spacing (d) between A3 and B1.  Also spacing (d/3) between A1- A2  and B1-B2.  If coloring is not possible I want to have another label for A and B categories.  Basically, below A1, A2, A3 there will be a label A and similarly for B.

Comment: Have a look at similar problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34885526/creating-bar-chart-with-different-groups-in-different-colors-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47796264/function-to-create-grouped-bar-plot) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502360/python-plot-grouped-bar-graph) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43554521/add-data-label-to-grouped-bar-chart-in-matplotlib). You first need to figure out a way to group them by category. Plotting them is a secondary task

Comment: Thanks again for your response but I am going to accept the response by @ZarakiKenpachi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set indexing and colors manually:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

labels= ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']
values= [2, 4, 3, 2.5, 3.5, 4]

# set indexing manually
index = np.array([0,1,2,4,5,6])
# plot bars with colors
bar_list = plt.bar(index, values, width=0.5, color=('r', 'r', 'r', 'b','b','b'))

plt.ylabel('Values', fontsize=14)
plt.xticks(index, labels, fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much; this is exactly what I want.  Is it also possible to decrease the spacing between A2-A3 and B2-B3? Can you also tell me how I can put secondary x label below A1 (M category), A2-3(N category), B1(M category), B2-B3(N category)?

Comment: @A.E to mnmipulate distances between bars change values inside index array like : np.array([0,1,1.7,4,5,5.7])